# Asp.net 3.5 forms authentication timeout

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, web-config

I have this codes in

```
 <authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="/Login" timeout="180" name="__Auth"     slidingExpiration="true" />
</authentication>
```

And Plesk panel Session  settings are as below :
   Authentication mode : Forms
   Sesion Timeout(minutes) : 180 
And this settings automatically adding a line to web.config aas below:

```
 <sessionState timeout="180" />
```

Everything seems good.
But session ends too early (about 10 min)
I could not find reason.

Answer (score 1):

Please include following code in web config in your application.

```
  <session State timeout="30" mode="In-proc" />
```

and also check time in

But you remove space in between session state and remove - in In-proc...

Answer (score 0):

Please include following code in your web.config file and try.

```
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="102400" executionTimeout="3600"/></httpRuntime>.
```

Comment: I had <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="8096" /></httpRuntime>.
Now changed.I'am trying.I will write with results.Thank you

Comment: Could you please explain the issue in detail that you were facing while logging .